# image is not loading using php echo

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to echo the table fields one by one.
But I can't echo the image field.
My code is:

```
if ($data->Prophylaxis_Indicated == 1) {
    echo "<td><span title='true_logo'> <img src='url('images/1-icon.png')' height='20' width='20'></span></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td> <span title='true_logo'><img src='url('images/0-icon.png')'height='20' width='20'></span></td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is you are trying to use blade syntax in controller.

use this code this will work

```
 if(($data->Prophylaxis_Indicated)==1){
                echo " <td><span title='true_logo'>
                <img src='images/1-icon.png'
                height='20' width='20'>
                </span></td>";

              }
              else{

               echo "<td> <span title='true_logo'>
               <img src='images/0-icon.png'
               height='20' width='20'>
               </span></td>";
             }
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing it this way: `..src='".asset('images/1-icon.png')."' height='20' width='20'/>...`

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
if(($data->Prophylaxis_Indicated)==1){
                echo " 
                <td>
                <span title='true_logo'>

                <img src='/../images/1-icon.png' height='20' width='20'> 
                </span>
                </td>";

              }
              else{

               echo "<td> <span title='true_logo'>
               <img src='/../images/0-icon.png' height='20' width='20'> 


               </span></td>";
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double underscore so it may not **cz syntax** error

```
 src="url('images/0-icon.png')"
```

**instead**

```
src='url('images/0-icon.png')'
```